# For complex objects like lists, tuples, dictionaries etc. what is return when i use the function id() to the list name?

Tags: python

there is a list

```
a=[1,2,3]
```

```
id(a[0])
id(a)
```

I know the return of id(a[0]) is the memory address of the first element in list a,but what's the meaning of id(a)?

Comment: The memory address of the list object…!?

Comment: `id` returns a *unique identifier* for whatever object you pass in. As a **CPython implementation detail** that *happens* to be the address of the PyObject header of whatever object you pass in. It really isn't useful to think of it that way, though. But in any case, it works the same for *all objects*. It isn't really clear what you don't understand.

Comment: The return value of `id` is implementation-dependent, so you shouldn't assign any meaning to it.

Answer (score 0):

[Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id)

`id()` gives the identity of object. As for the `id()` of list/tuples, try it:

```
a = [1,2]
b = [1,2]

print(id(a))
a.append(3)

print(id(a), id(b))
```

Output:

```
139875189735984
139875189735984 139875189738544
```

As we see from the above example that the list id would be same even after making modifications to the list. I expect the resilt to be same across all object types